# With Synergy, Can You Switch Monitor Configurations On The Fly?

Tags: multiple-monitors, synergy

If I switch my monitor configuration, can Synergy recognize this and switch its configuration on the fly?

For example, I have a triple-monitor setup on one computer, and a solo monitor on another. I can press a button to make each computer trade monitors with the other, via an HDMI switch. How can I get Synergy to recognize this change automatically when it happens?

If this is not possible within Synergy, I could set up a script to run automatically when I flip the HDMI switch. Could such a script get me this functionality? For example, perhaps the script could close Synergy, change the configuration file, then restart it?

Answer (score 1):

Switching configs on the fly isn't possible right now, but it's something we're working on in Synergy version 2.0. I'm on the Synergy development team at Symless.

Comment: I just bought Synergy, and I really want to be able to do this! If I could toggle my center monitor between my windows and macos machines with the click of a button, I'd be really pleased. Any updates on that timeline for 2.0?